# What happens when a snapshot is deleted

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I have a tree of snapshots taken about once an hour as I progressed through a rather tricky server setup.  Now that I'm done, I would like to get rid of the snapshots, but I gather that these are actually differencing drives.  If that's the case, does it not mean that deleting a snapshot will in fact revert me back to a previous point in time.  Or does it mean that deleting a snapshot merges the changed bits into the parent VHD.

Comment: Quick question, is this going to be a production server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you delete the snapshots you will (obviously) lose the .avhd files and it will merge to the .vhd and you will be left with your current environment all contained in the starting .vhd file.

Answer (score 1):

Note that as the files merge it can take some time, during which your machine will be inaccessible.  Depending on how many changes and how large your avhd's are it could take an hour or more so plan accordingly.  They merge starts the first time you stop a system after deleting the snapshot.

P.S. You won't be able to see the merge progress in SCVMM is you use this tool  You will have to go to Hyper-V Manager to see the progress.